# Why is the carbon atom omitted from the molecular formula?

Tags: organic-chemistry, erratum

In my chemistry textbook, the following reaction was given:

[image]

I have two questions related to the marked in orange boxes/parts of the image:

1. Why is the molecule symbolized by $\ce{(CH3)3Cl}$ instead of $\ce{(CH3)3CCl}$ or $\ce{C(CH3)3Cl}$? Why is the carbon atom omitted?
2. Why is the "inversion" molecule with a $\ce{CH2}$ instead of a $\ce{CH3}$ attached to it?

I would greatly appreciate an answer. This is high-school chemistry that I have just learned and I am a bit confused.

Thanks :)

Comment: Typos!  Just bad editing. You are correct in your thinking. You should point these out to your instructor

Comment: Often the publisher has a list of errata for a book. You might try and look that up. **Kudos for you studying diligently enough to catch the mistakes.**

Comment: Step 2 in your text should have water as the nucleophile, not hydroxide. Hydroxide would lead to elimination to isobutylene, not substitution.